# Rust .exe fails to open on Windows

Tags: rust

I'm building an app with rust. Using `--cargo run --release` successfully compiles the app and runs it, bringing up the GUI window for the app. However, when I manually open `target/release/MyApp.exe`, nothing happens. Checked when `myapp.exe` was last modifies shows that running `--cargo run --release` is updating the app.

I'm on windows 10 so I added "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc" as the build target.

```
[package]
name = "MuTexAlpha"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Webb Hinton <wyhinton189@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
fltk = "0.15.1"
serde = "1.0.118"
texture-synthesis = "0.8.0"
rand = "0.7.3"
num_cpus = "1.13.0"
uuid = { version = "0.8", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
image = "0.23.12"
glob = "0.3.0"
dyn-clone = "1.0.4"
colored = "2.0.0"
arboard = "1.1.0"
id_tree = "1.7.0"
id_tree_layout = "2.0.1"
typetag = "0.1"
serde_json = "1.0.61"
snafu = "0.6.10"
palette = "0.5.0"
indicatif = "0.14.0"

[build]
target = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"
```

1. Isn't the .exe in release the same program being executed with `--cargo run --release`?
2. I have some file dependencies in my app, might this be the cause of the issue? (compiling the app gives no errors, however)
3. Could this be something specifically related to windows?

Comment: Maybe it needs some dlls to run, it shows any kind of error? Or either can be the code, if you are using winapi probably thats the case, there are some weird thing about creating windows with the windows api that depending on the context they show up or not

Comment: @cdecompilador running --release gives no errors, and I get no errors when trying to open the .exe. I am using winapi, do you have any more information about the weird behavior you describe? I'm just really confused as to why ```cargo -run release``` would work fine but opening the .exe does not.

Comment: Those file dependencies you are mentioning. Try copying your exec to your app root instead. `cargo run --release` uses your app root as working directory but if you try to run the exe directly, your working dir would be `./target/release/`which possibly could prevent it from getting a valid path to your dependencies (depending on how you include them of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might just be a shot in the dark, but are you opening the `exe` using Windows Explorer?

Open up a `cmd.exe` window and try running it from there.

Comment: Yes I'm running in File Explorer! I tried running in command prompt and it game me and file::io::error, so I know where to go from here

Comment: We can help if you provide the exact error code/stacktrace. While we're at it, maybe add some relevant code to your question as well.